# Every album has the same icon

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, downloading, music

I downloaded Shuttle(free version) to listen to music on my Xiaomi Redmi 3 Pro.

I downloaded a lot of music albums(only mp3 files), but the last one created a problem.

When I downloaded this album, its main icon(so the image of the album) has took the place of every other album's icon in the app and I don't know the reason.

Is this a problem of the 'download' directory? Or is this a problem of Shuttle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problably in the song property there isn't the album tag. You can modify it and add the name of the album using a Music tag editor. You can also change the pick of the album.
I use the app "Star Music Tag Editor"